# Using Custom Javascript Libraries in Angular

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive

I found a javascript library "https://github.com/jvail/spatiasql.js" that I want to use with angular. I know I could just include it in the name of my scripts in my header, but I want to be able to inject it into my angular modules to access it from the controllers. I believe to do this I will need to have a custom built angular directive from this javascript library, correct? If so how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a factory that returns the library's namespace object, e.g.

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("myModule")
        .factory("sql", SqlFactory);

    SqlFactory.$inject = ['$window'];

    function SqlFactory($window) {
        return $window.spatiasql;
    }
})();
```

Then you can inject it:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("myModule")
        .service("someService", SomeService);

    SomeService.$inject = ["sql"];

    function SomeService(sql) {
        var db = new sql.DataBase();
    }
})();
```

Comment: nice one, but why the $? Isn't that limited to AngularJs internals?

Comment: I typically use it to indicate that it's simply an injectable wrapper around an existing library.  You can call it whatever you like.

Comment: right, I'd stay away from $ but it's a nice solution still

Comment: Ok. There are just a few things I am uncertain of. When you say "return spatiasql" how does angular know that it's referring to "spatiasql.js"? Also, the syntax for creating a database is "var db = new sql.Database()" (I can see you read some of the API, thank you. Because we're using the injected object named $SQL, do we have to use the object name "$SQL" as a prefix to using any of its code? ex. "var db = new $SQL.sql.Database()" ?

Comment: Angular doesn't know what you're referring to.  The whole point of this is to make it so.  You can just use the object without doing this as @Maarten suggested, but if you want to inject it, you'll have to do something like this.  The reason I was able to do `new sql.Database()` is because Angular's DI assigns the injected members to the function arguments positionally.  This means you can rename the argument from $SQL to sql (in the function signature, not in the dependency array) and it'll work just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not understanding what you mean by "make a factory that return's the libraries namespace object". I guess I'm not sure about how libraries work in general. At the link I gave (https://github.com/jvail/spatiasql.js) there are many files and folders. Do I just include "js/spatiasql.js" in the angular project, or the entire library? and how would I include this in the header. I'm not a complete noob, I know how to include scripts from CDN's but I've never done it from a small library like this.

Comment: You need to include whatever scripts are required for what you're trying to do.  The documentation might tell you which scripts to include, and if you're unsure you can just add them all or be more conservative and add the others as you need them.  The factory can return the namespace the library uses (e.g. "jQuery", "angular", "require") or you can create a custom injectable that has more specific properties.

Answer (score 0):

No need to inject it in order to access functions from it in your controllers. You can just call it's methods from you controllers.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Then what is the purpose of injection into modules at all? I looked it up but I don't REALLY understand.

Comment: injecting is an Angular construct, which is meant to make testing easier because you can swap out the real object for a mock one. With non-Angular code you cannot use injection into Angular objects. The way the other answer does it seems like a good idea though

Answer (score 0):

Injecting is not an angular construct. It is an implementation of the inversion of control design pattern. It is one of the foundations of modern object oriented design. The purpose of it is to make unit tests possible. It leads to code that isn't tightly coupled. DI allows you to code to an interface rather than an implementation.

Comment: Looks like I need to read a design patterns book. Thanks. I'm still a student and didn't take this class yet.

Comment: right it is, but in this case it is something the framework supports in it's own implementation, should have been more clear on that.